# how can i get the value of text view in recyclerview item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, textview

This is my adapter for `RecyclerView`. How can I get the value of `deckName` in another activity?

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public RelativeLayout deckLayout;
    public LinearLayout countsLayout;
    public ImageButton deckExpander;
    public ImageButton indentView;
    public  TextView deckName;
    public TextView deckNew, deckLearn, deckRev;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        deckLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.DeckPickerHoriz);
        countsLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.counts_layout);
        deckExpander = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_expander);
        indentView = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_indent);
        deckName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_name);
        deckNew = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_new);
        deckLearn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_lrn);
        deckRev = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_rev);


    }
}
```

I want get this value and compare it with a string here:

```
final int itemCount = mDeckListAdapter.getItemCount();
DeckAdapter a = new DeckAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), getApplicationContext());
for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
    //  final CharSequence text = DeckAdapter.ViewHolder.deckName.getText();
    if (text.equals(di)){
        mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).itemView.performClick();
    }
}
```

but this code doesn't really work.

Comment: Can't you use this to get the text: `mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i).deckName.getText().toString()` ?

Comment: @Nicolas Maltais no cant resolve symbol deckname

Comment: Are you trying to implement item click on recyclerview?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
String title = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
```

I used like

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            String title = ((TextView) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) { }
    }));
```

Comment: Worked in 2022, thanks you brooooo <3

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

Use below code where you want to retrieve the value from textview, so that you can iterate the value of each textview from your RecyclerView.

```
for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++)
{
  View view=mRecyclerView.getChildAt(i); // This will give you entire row(child) from RecyclerView
   if(view!=null)
     {
       TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deckpicker_name);
        String text=textView.getText().toString();
        if (text.equals(di)){
             // Do your stuff, after comparison
        }
      }
}
```

I have not tested this, but hope it works for you somehow.

Comment: tnx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. It works for me. 
Just Paste in Your Activity or Fragment
rvSelectedProductList = Recyclerview
selectedItemAdapter = RecyclerView Adapter

```
      rvSelectedProductList.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                final int itemCount = selectedItemAdapter.getItemCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
                    TextView tvSelling = rvSelectedProductList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.tvSelling);
                    TextView textViewDrawerTitle = rvSelectedProductList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.tvCartQty);


                    String totalamount = tvSelling.getText().toString();
                    String qty = textViewDrawerTitle.getText().toString();
                    System.out.println("qty" + qty);
                    System.out.println("total" + totalamount);
                }
                rvSelectedProductList.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.but this code will execute when press any place in recycler view.
If you want to  action when press title object only you must put event on title

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    String title=view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    title1, 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) { }
}));
```